# JSONException: Value 1 at page of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android,I am creating an app in which i need to add params :- pageNumber and device token to get the api response but i am getting an exception in following code :- **JSONException: Value 1 at page of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject** Here is my code :- [image]
[image]

Comment: There is nothing with your code. The exception is probably coming from somewhere else and not from the code you have written. I would also suggest in your `getAllPushMessages` function call, simply add a `has("page")` check instead. Because if the `page` key is already there, you don't need to again put its value.

Comment: Thanks for this @che10 , yeah!! the exception was due to some another line of code.